# Where to manage keyboard shortcuts in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anyone know where to create keyboard shortcuts in Windows 7?

For instance, I would like to bind the launching of google Chrome to a keyboard shortcut, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a shortcut and assign it a hotkey:
[image]
That hotkey should be globally accessible.

Also, applications that are [pinned to the taskbar](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-taskbar) are accessible with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> (depending on their position on the taskbar).