# How do I remove all shortcut (.lnk) hotkeys from Windows?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry

#### The problem

In the past I've tried to bind a file manager (directory opus) to Win + E (which didn't work) before settling on Win + Shift + E using [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/411766/where-to-manage-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-7). I feel like trying that is biting me in the butt now years later with One Commander's Win + E registry hack failing to work. It works fine on my laptop, just not on this computer (showing an explorer.exe error window saying application not found). Directory Opus has been uninstalled for a long, long time now and no shortcuts to it still exist on my PC as far as I know (I've searched using [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com)).

#### Recent attempt at solving

I've searched the registry for relevant keys to Directory Opus and their developer and have removed them manually, but pressing that keyboard shortcut (Win Shift E) still triggers an error sound in Windows (it used to pop up an error window saying the shortcut/executable is not found).

#### Question

How do I clear all shortcut hotkeys that were created in this way?

Not asking anyone to debug third party software for me though. Just wondering if I could clear these shortcuts that Windows seems to remember in some way. I've seen [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1588715/where-is-hotkeys-for-desktop-shortcut-stored-in-windows-registry-and-how-to-chan), but I'm not trying to add shortcuts, I'm trying to remove them.

---

#### Attempts based on responses

I've tried what Kamil recommended in the comments below:

> Does the method allow you to assign the same hotkey to another shortcut? Hopefully this will overwrite the old assignment. Then, with the new shortcut existing, there may be a way to clear the hotkey. I don't use Windows so I cannot test the idea, but it's something I would try.

All I found that now any time I try to use the windows key, or Win + Shift, it comes up as Ctrl + Alt in the shortcut properties window. I don't think this was the case years ago. But the problem is not resolved

Comment: Could it be there's still a shortcut to Directory Opus somewhere hidden in your start menu that has that key combination defined?